# How to create n different arrays with 6 random numbers each. - Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to create 1 - 12 arrays of 6 random numbers each.
At the moment I can only create one. So I don't know how to loop this.

**This is my code so far:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function schleife() {           

  var arr = [];
  var krams = [];   

  for(i=1; i<=6; i++) { 
    var zufall = Math.floor((Math.random() * 49) + 1);          
    krams.push(zufall++);
  } 

  arr.push(krams.toString() + "<br /><br />");          
  $(".bsp2").append(arr);

}       

function uebertrag() {  
  schleife();       
}
</script>
```

Comment: I do not see a loop of `12`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create new function: e.g. getArrayOfRandomNumbers

```
function getArrayOfRandomNumbers() {
  var krams = []

  for(var i=1; i<=6; i++) { 
    var zufall = Math.floor((Math.random() * 49) + 1)          
    krams.push(zufall++)
  }

  return krams
}
```

And now you can invoke this function in loop:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
  var arrayOfRandomNumber = getArrayOfRandomNumbers()
  //do something with this array, e.g. append

  $(".bsp2").append(arrayOfRandomNumber.toString())
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand it, so far. 

How do I get the values my 12 arrays?

for example
 $(".bsp2").append(arrayOfRandomNumber2.toString());
 $(".bsp2").append(arrayOfRandomNumber3.toString());

did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function schleife(iRange, jRange) {  
    var array = []

    for (i = 1; i <= iRange; i++) {
        var krams = [];   

        for(j = 1; j <= jRange; j++) { 
          var zufall = Math.floor((Math.random() * 49) + 1);          
          krams.push(zufall++);
        } 

        array.push(krams);
        $(".bsp2").append(krams + "<br /><br />");
    }

    return array;
}           

schleife(12, 6);
```

Comment: But how can I get the values of each array then?

Comment: Sorry, have you tried it? I don't get any results. What could I have done wrong?

Comment: @Marcel, you have to call the functions so it can work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you havenchyk. I was able to make it with your code!
Great! I'm really happy up to this point. ;-)

That's how it looks now:

```
function getArrayOfRandomNumbers() {

    var krams = [];   

    while(krams.length < 6) {
        var zufall = Math.floor((Math.random() * 49) + 1);
        var found = false;

        for(var i=0; i<krams.length; i++) {
            if(krams[i] == zufall) {
                found = true; 
                break
            }
        }

        if(!found){
            krams.push(zufall++);
        }        
    }    

    return krams;
}

function getArrays() {

    function compareNumbers(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    var results = [];

    for (var j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
        var arrayOfRandomNumber = getArrayOfRandomNumbers();
        //do something with this array
        results.push(arrayOfRandomNumber.splice(0, 6).sort(compareNumbers).toString()+"<br /><br />");
    }

    $(".bsp2").append(results[1]);
    $(".bsp2").append(results[2]);
    $(".bsp2").append(results[3]);
    $(".bsp2").append(results[4]);
    $(".bsp2").append(results[5]);
    $(".bsp2").append(results[6]);
    $(".bsp2").append(results[7]);
    $(".bsp2").append(results[8]);
    $(".bsp2").append(results[9]);
    $(".bsp2").append(results[10]);
}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you can mark my answer as useful. It's a SO convention :)